# Are Stackoverflow like all-in-one style posts welcome?

Tags: discussion

I am mostly involved with the stackoverflow community of the SE sites. There are some posts which are self-answered: the question lists a bunch of issues, and the answer is going over them one by one. Here are two examples: [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781634/aggregation-in-pandas).

I have found many good posts here on orbits / conic sections. For example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2141482/590567) one. I haven't found an extensive description of how to deal with Keplerian orbits, something similar to the Pandas examples from Stackoverflow.

I think I am capable of writing an extensive post containing most of the issues people encounter with when dealing with orbits. Are these Stackoverflow-like all-in-one posts welcome here?

Comment: A similar post on [relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802279/examples-and-counterexamples-of-relations-which-satisfy-certain-properties) posted recently (probably not exactly the same: the post I linked is still quite specific). The reception is okay (+9/-5 for the post and +7/-3 for Xander's answer).

Comment: That's indeed not that bad, nice example!

Comment: Maybe not exactly the same thing, but maybe loosely related: [Would “organizer posts” be useful/welcome here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3967)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### FAQ-Style Questions

The linked questions are examples of FAQ-style questions:  the question post poses a *number* of (possibly related) questions, and then each answer seeks to address one of those questions.  Generally speaking, such questions are not on-topic on Math SE.  We expect questions here to be narrowly focused, and centered on a single problem or mathematical confusion.

FAQ-style questions are, as rschwieb suggests, less searchable.  They are also more prone to disorganization, as users other than the original asker/answerer may have alternative answers which are likely to get lost in the shuffle.  It would be better to pose each question independently (though it might be reasonable to interlink those questions).

#### Self-Answering

It also seems that the question of self-answering is implicit in the question, i.e. is it acceptable to self-answer a question?

In general, asking-and-answering a question is perfectly fine.  Indeed, the software and design philosophy of SE encourages users to answer their own questions.  However, there are some things to keep in mind:

- One of the primary goals of Math SE (and the SE network in general) is to build a repository of questions and answers which are of interest and use to a large number of people.  The goal here is *not* to create a solution guide to a particular text book, nor to show off esoteric knowledge.  When you ask-and-answer a question, you need to make sure that both the question and answer meet the site quality standards (indeed, we might even ask for a little *more*, since there is an implicit claim that the question is going to be helpful to a large number of users—it certainly *isn't* going to be terribly helpful to the asker, since the asker already knows the answer).

  The site  standards are summarized in the meta  topic  [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  Note, also, that  any Q&A in this style should contribute something *new* to the site, and should not (except under very rare circumstances) duplicate an existing question.
- A similar, though distinct, situation in which self-answering may be desirable is in the context of a [question rewrite](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites).  In this case, it is perhaps *expected* (though by no means required) that you will want to answer the question yourself.  Again, just  make sure that the work you do complies with site  guidelines.
- It is also not unreasonable for an asker to pose a question, then have answers (or hints) given in the comments.  In such a case, it is entirely appropriate for the original asker to take what they have learned in the comments and write an answer.  Again, please ensure that the question and answer meet site quality standards.

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is far for forgiving of users perspectives: a position that would agree fully with your second bullet, but hesitate on the first.  I'm glad that you clarified that PSQ-looking questions, followed by an answer by the same asker of the PSQ is NOT appropriate. I also think the first bullet would be improved by ruling out its use when the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @amWhy I've made some modifications to address your concerns (and suggested another use case).  I felt that "don't duplicate" was implicit in the comments regarding quality, but it can't hurt to  be explicit.

Comment: More mispellings and typos I made in first sentence (per a brief discussion elsewhere!).  I meant only to say that your position seemed far to lenient wrt such question/self answer questions, compared to a great number of users.  But no matter now, because I think your adjustments make it clear when and when not, it is appropriate to ask a question, and then answer it.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Posts like the two you linked ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781634/aggregation-in-pandas)) would not be appropriate for this site.

The problem is that asking multiple questions in a post is going to be less searchable and the format makes it awkward for people other than the self-answerer to answer.

Note that I do not say self-answering is of any issue. Indeed, we encourage self-answering, but usually expect that you originally faced some problem finding the answer. It's not recommended to make question-answer posts when you are really not facing any problems with the question.  It is a better use-case for people who figure out their own problem after being stuck initially.  Exceptions to this general rule would be made according to the quality and value of the post.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with the statement that a question should be asked before an answer is known (to the asker).  If someone has a good Q&A pair, i.e. a question of general interest and a good answer, and that Q&A pair does not yet exist on the site, I don't see any reason why one should not post the question and answer.  Of course, every question I've asked is of that kind, so maybe I'm biased?

Comment: @XanderHenderson To me, that strays too far into the depths of treating the site like a repository.  The perverse incentives fueled by the ability to post any number of question-answer pairs do not seem palatable.  I guess I will emphasize what I'm saying to be that it should **not be absolutely prohibited** but it should also **not be encouraged** unless the post has some exceptional quality.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I believe I have, at one point in the past, named a user who had a hundred or more posts that amounted to creating a solutions manual for a book, in self-answered style, on this site.  At least when the user faces an actual problem, they are naturally limited by their working attention. That is, one would not be likely to be actively engaged with a dozen or more problems at a time.

Comment: I do not mean to suggest that any ol' question should be asked-and-answered, but I find the idea of restricting self-answers to those questions which are answered in the process of asking, commenting, etc to be far too constraining.  There are other circumstances in which questions are reasonably self-answered, e.g. when the question is of broad interest.

Comment: And, as with anything on this site, quality matters.  A user who posts hundreds of low-quality Q&A pairs ought be discouraged (by the community, or via moderation tools).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Like I said, I am not suggesting a prohibition, just a reasonable quality bar. I don't know which one you mean by "restriction." I gather you *do* agree with restriction to prevent the misuse I'm worried about.  I don't think "not recommended" can really be labeled a restriction.

Comment: @XanderHenderson reviewing again, I can see how the "stipulate" sentence clashed with the next sentence and could have led to this interpretation. I've edited to rectify that. If there's any disagreement left I don't see that it's with what is written currently.

Comment: Downvoter, you. may want to explain if you disagreed with the latter half of the post (new edition or old) or if you are a fan of multi-part questions and answers.

Comment: It reads better, but it still seems like you are implying that the only (or best?) use-case for self-answering is if an asker discovers the answer in the process of getting feedback on the question.  However, anyone motivated to read the comments here will likely figure it out.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I've tried my best to eliminate the interpretation using **only.**  I am not sure there is a **better** use-case. But certainly it is the **main** use-case, is it not?

Comment: I have  no idea what the  main  use-case  is.   Do you have  any data to support a  conclusion?  Regarding good/better/best, my favorite  use case is in the context of rewrites.

Comment: I agree with you, @rschwieb.  I'm not fond of folks posting a question they solve two years ago, and thinking "I'm going to show just how clever I am and maybe earn some good, quick rep for it".  Certainly there are rare altruists who see a question that has no canonical answer, and they are committed to providing one.  But from my experience over ten years, most of the times I've seen someone post a question and instantaneously post an answer, they already were, or soon became, "show boaters", folks who wanted to be seen as clever, or folks who were seeking rep.

Comment: @rschwieb  To get to my point about agreement, I am fine with self answered posts as long as they are good questions (context etc.) and were, initially, a problem the OP struggled with.  Even if posted seeking help, and they later, maybe after some comments, figure it out, and then post as an answer.

Comment: And @Xander you failed to address my point that many folks who think they have a clever answer to a question, post the question, and an answer .... which turns out to be a dupe, due to their failure to search in the first place.  One's own perception of competence and cleverness does not justify subjecting the entire site to a show-off.

Comment: @amWhy In my answer, I wrote: "The site standards are summarized in the meta topic How to ask a good question. Note, also, that any Q&A in this style should contribute something new to the site, and should not (except under very rare circumstances) duplicate an existing question."  This seems to address the issue of duplicates...  I also addressed the issue showing off, i.e. the point is not to show off esoteric knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Xander.  That makes a lot of sense, I think I missed that last point you included in your answer.  Cheers!

Comment: @amWhy No worries. :D

Comment: @XanderHenderson:  what are the very rare exceptional circumstances under which duplicating an existing question is acceptable?

Comment: Duplicating an existing question may be acceptable in the context of the [question rewriting policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites), or if one is attempting to create an abstract canonical Q&A pair for a question which is frequently duplicated.  In either case, the end goal is likely to have the existing question closed as a duplicate of the newer question, or even merged into the newer question.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, @XanderHenderson

Comment: @XanderHenderson "I have no idea what the main use-case is. Do you have any data to support a conclusion?" I do not understand this: what sort of data could there be?  Am I to gather a random sample of self-answered questions, evaluate whether or not they adhered to what I suggested, and then report?  First of all it is exceedingly onerous, but also it seems backward: most of the time policy should guide posts, not the other way around.  But even with that said, (cont'd)

Comment: ... I am going to let the situation lie as it is.  I have found out that [the current wording of the advice on the matter](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) clearly invites the "warehousing solutions" use-case. I think that without refinement this puts us in an untenable position, but hey maybe it won't ever see problematic explotation.

Comment: @rschwieb You made the claim regarding a main use-case---I did not.  If you are going to make a claim, then the onus is on you to support that claim.  I do not claim that there is a "main" use-case, and very explicitly stated that I have no idea what the main use-case is, as I have no data about how self-answering is used in the wild.  I am also confused by the phrase "warehousing solutions".  Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I need an answer for the question "what data do you expect?" not some patronizing explanation of rational discourse.  I *think* the most relevant data is previous discussions in meta, but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.  That's where *I* formed the impression. "Warehousing solutions" is exactly what it sounds like, systematic storage of question and answer pairs, including even use of the site as a master solution manual.

Comment: Regarding data:  I don't understand what you mean by "main use-case".  My understanding is that you are asserting that this is the most common case, in which case a random sample of self-answered questions would be appropriate.  Regarding "warehousing solutions"---isn't that what SE explicitly sets out to do? Isn't the goal of SE to create a repository of questions and answers (e.g. problems and solutions)?  I don't think that I understand the issue (or maybe I am missing some subtle connotation?).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Let's say "main use-case" is more like "intended use-case."  But honestly I don't know how many share this value with me.  I thought we were supposed to be striking a balance between being a repository and being responsive to people struggling with problems.  I think focusing too much on hoarding question-answer pairs will lead to a corpus that is hard to use, especially considering people are not very good at checking what's already there.

Comment: All I'm arguing for is to leave at least some of the responsibility for filtration of self-answered posts with the poster, rather than foisting all the moderation responsibility on the (overworked) moderation community.